# Water supply plumbing changing of pipe size

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

Just a quick 1...I'm installing a jojo and I have ¾ supply which I'll be feeding the jojo with...but I was thinking can't I run the ¾ pipe for about 2 meters and than upstream the pipe (increase the diameter of the pipe to a 32mm pipe hpde  and than back into a ¾ copper pipe .

Why I'm asking is would this allow more water to flow through that ±10 meters of pipe?  or should I rather take a ¾ pipe and upstream it to a 25mm pipe and feed the jojo.

Comment: No idea what a "jojo" is local slang for. Unless it's something that requires a HUGE flow rate, there's no reason to even try to upscale 3/4" pipe. And not much benefit if it does require a huge flow rate.

Comment: A jojo appears to be South African jargon for a water tank, sometimes used for grey/rain water, sometimes used as emergency water storage (e.g. if muni water goes out).

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate the feed back...I'm taking your info into consideration and not going with the 32mm but rather sticking to the 25mm hpde .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 3/4 supply pipe is 3/4 for many meters before you get it, there's very little benefit to increasing the size for 10 meters after you get it. The reduction in dynamic head (pipe friction) over 10 meters will be quite limited compared to typically quite a long run of 3/4" pipe between any larger supply pipe and your service entrance.

Comment: Ohokey so I won't be actually be increasing the volume of water entering the tank ?

Comment: Not to a particularly significant degree, unless your 3/4 supply line is very, very short.